# In FosUserBundle, get old and new password of a User to duplicate password reset on a third-party database

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

I'm using the **FosUserBundle** to manage my web users, and also through an API to log in a mobile app.
I have a `resetPasswordAction` API method to enable password reset within the app.

But I'm also using a **third-party database** for some of the users which allows me to manage their roles, so these users have to register/log in with their third-party credentials. Then I copy the data in the FosUser database.

Now, if they want to reset their password, obviously it'll be done on my FosUser database with my API method, but not on the third-party one. What I want to achieve is **catch the email of the User, its old password, and its new password**, so that I can use the third-party API method **to also update its password on the third-party database**.

I've tried creating an Event Listener, but `RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED` receives the `FilterUserResponseEvent`, so I can only catch only the email and the new password.

I a bit stuck here, so if anyone has a clue on how I can manage this, that would be a great help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to persist the old password on your User entity (that extends the FOS User entity) as a field.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="old_password", type="string")
 */
private $oldPassword;
```

You'll have to create a command to migrate all users current password to the new "old_password" column in your database.

This also gets tricky because you'll have to populate that entity field every time the User changes passwords and also populate it when the user is created. This adds a lot of complexity to any controllers that handle the user interaction.

Then in your event listener, you'll have to get that old password from the User entity, do your API posts, and if all that goes without exception, then update the database and set "old_password" to current password.

Comment: could work yes, but in terms of security it's not so good! or with a hashed $oldPassword, but this means having a decoding function too.

Comment: Can you capture the old password before you send them to the form? Send them to an endpoint in a controller, capture the pass, then forward them to the FOS endpoint? (Which I'm assuming is /resetting and handled by FOS.)

Comment: I have to see if something like this can be done... still not sure about the security issues of these methods... :)

Comment: Security is not going to be easy sending passwords over HTTP or storing on your own server in plaintext.

Good luck.